# js how to print the objectName to console

Tags: javascript

When using the webdev tools console, if type a browser object, it returns console

```
> console
Console {  }
> console+""
"[object Console]"
> console.log(console)
undefined
> Console {  }
```

Works in this way for all browser objects;
But if I do it with my own object, the output don't have my objectName(MyObj), only "Object" like this:

```
> var MyObj=function(){}
undefined
> var instance = new MyObj();
undefined
> instance
Object {  }
> instance+""
"[object Object]"
> console.log(instance);
undefined
Object {  }
```

Is there a way to make my objects output behavior be the same of browser objects ? And, can anyone anyone explain me why ?

Comment: `concsole` output is not standardized and highly engine-specific. You shouldn't care.

Comment: Try to use a named function for your constructor instead of an anonymous one.

Comment: @Bergi, I got the point of console output... but can you give me a sample of "named functions"? if it is a `funcion MyObj(){}` like, no it don't work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `toString()` method in `MyObj.prototype`:

```
MyObj.prototype.toString = function(){ return "[object MyObj]";}
```

#### Example

```
var MyObj = function(){};    
MyObj.prototype.toString = function(){ return "[object MyObj]"; };

var instance = new MyObj();

console.log(instance + "");
// "[object MyObj]"
```

Comment: Yeah, but it only solve part of the question. the (instance+"")

Comment: @ton: Well, there's an implicit one-question-per-post rule. But to answer the second one: the built-in objects use the same trick.

Comment: @Zeta, the question is "how to reproduce the same behavior", your answer do not do it. Only the "toString" behavior is reproduced. the console.log do not. nor the object output itself.

Comment: It does forget to mention exactly why `console.log(console)` writes `Console { }` whereas `console.log(instance)` writes `Object { }` instead of `MyObj { }`. But Zeta has a point, there is like 4 questions in this single question. They have answered at least 2 of them.

Comment: @RGraham, I agree, although I already know this solution, and not be What do I expected. I failed to develop a clearer question. I'll accept this answer and ask again in another topic more clearly.

Comment: Second try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068639/js-why-my-output-is-object-instead-of-myobj

Comment: @ton: This code _does_ print `MyObj {}` in the latest chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L43Gh.png Maybe different browsers give different results.

Comment: @Cerbrus, understood, tested, you're right, but in firefox it's not true. Anyway I got the point, the console output format is browser specifc.