# JS - Why my output is Object { } Instead of: MyObj { }?

Tags: javascript

When using the webdev tools console, if type a browser object, it returns console

```
> console
Console {  }
> console.log(console)
undefined
> Console {  }
```

Works in this way for all browser objects; But if I do it with my own object, the output don't have my objectName(MyObj), only "Object" like this:

```
> var MyObj=function(){}
undefined
> var instance = new MyObj();
undefined
> instance
Object {  }
> console.log(instance);
undefined
Object {  }
```

Question: 
Why my output is `Object { }` Instead of: `MyObj { }` ?

NOTE: This is my second try to clarify this question, the first one was [js how to print the objectName to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067815/js-how-to-print-the-objectname-to-console) and it was not effective. Please do not make a simple response like "write a toString() function" it's not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for the SAME behavior not only on toString (intance+'') output, but too in "instance" output itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/nano88uq/  prints `MyObj{}`

Comment: __Don't__ re-post the same question when the answers you first get aren't satisfactory.

Comment: if you investigate the `Console { ... }` object that is returned you will find you can expand `__proto__: Console > __proto__: Object > ...`. this shows you that console ultimately is a decendant of the `Object { }` object just like your custom object. What the console is returning to you is not the object name but the type of object you are creating.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I wrote another Question because it was suggested by Zeta claiming that I was doing a lot of questions in one post. I don't think it is the case of -1

Comment: Sure, but don't copy the exact question and just post it again. Separate out the different questions. I'm not saying you should post more questions about this subject, though. The original question has all the info you need on this.

Comment: If you look better it's not the same. I remove the toString references that give a acceptable status to Zeta response.

Answer (score 0):

Because `MyObj` inherits from built-in `Object`. The console outputs as if it is `Function`, `Array`, `Object`, etc. but not what you've created an object which is just an instance. So, it just outputs that which are in prototype chain.